# Raspberry Pi 3 emulating bluetooth keyboard running server

Tags: raspbian-stretch, bluetooth

I'm trying to emulate bluetooth keyboard on raspberry pi 3. I'm trying to connect my RPI3 with my lapbtop first via btk_server.py code which I got from github.
I downloaded the code from github and followed the instruction from following link:

http://yetanotherpointlesstechblog.blogspot.com/2016/04/emulating-bluetooth-keyboard-with.html?m=1

everything seems fine until I run btk_server.py code after changing MY_ADDRESS to my RPI3's BD Address.

Here's the btk_server.py code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

from optparse import OptionParser, make_option

import os

import sys

import uuid

import dbus

import dbus.service

import dbus.mainloop.glib

import time

import bluetooth

from bluetooth import *





import gtk

from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop





#

#define a bluez 5 profile object for our keyboard

#

class BTKbBluezProfile(dbus.service.Object):

    fd = -1



    @dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1",

                                    in_signature="", out_signature="")

    def Release(self):

            print("Release")

            mainloop.quit()



    @dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1",

                                    in_signature="", out_signature="")

    def Cancel(self):

            print("Cancel")



    @dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1", in_signature="oha{sv}", out_signature="")

    def NewConnection(self, path, fd, properties):

            self.fd = fd.take()

            print("NewConnection(%s, %d)" % (path, self.fd))

            for key in properties.keys():

                    if key == "Version" or key == "Features":

                            print("  %s = 0x%04x" % (key, properties[key]))

                    else:

                            print("  %s = %s" % (key, properties[key]))







    @dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1", in_signature="o", out_signature="")

    def RequestDisconnection(self, path):

            print("RequestDisconnection(%s)" % (path))



            if (self.fd > 0):

                    os.close(self.fd)

                    self.fd = -1



    def __init__(self, bus, path):

            dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, path)





#

#create a bluetooth device to emulate a HID keyboard, 

# advertize a SDP record using our bluez profile class

#

class BTKbDevice():

    #change these constants 

    MY_ADDRESS="B8:27:EB:12:5B:04"

    MY_DEV_NAME="DeskPi_BTKb"



    #define some constants

    P_CTRL =17  #Service port - must match port configured in SDP record

    P_INTR =19  #Service port - must match port configured in SDP record#Interrrupt port  

    PROFILE_DBUS_PATH="/bluez/yaptb/btkb_profile" #dbus path of  the bluez profile we will create

    SDP_RECORD_PATH = sys.path[0] + "/sdp_record.xml" #file path of the sdp record to laod

    UUID="00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"





    def __init__(self):



        print("Setting up BT device")



        self.init_bt_device()

        self.init_bluez_profile()





    #configure the bluetooth hardware device

    def init_bt_device(self):





        print("Configuring for name "+BTKbDevice.MY_DEV_NAME)



        #set the device class to a keybord and set the name

        os.system("hciconfig hcio class 0x002540")

        os.system("hciconfig hcio name " + BTKbDevice.MY_DEV_NAME)



        #make the device discoverable

        os.system("hciconfig hcio piscan")





    #set up a bluez profile to advertise device capabilities from a loaded service record

    def init_bluez_profile(self):



        print("Configuring Bluez Profile")



        #setup profile options

        service_record=self.read_sdp_service_record()



        opts = {

            "ServiceRecord":service_record,

            "Role":"server",

            "RequireAuthentication":False,

            "RequireAuthorization":False

        }



        #retrieve a proxy for the bluez profile interface

        bus = dbus.SystemBus()

        manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez","/org/bluez"), "org.bluez.ProfileManager1")



        profile = BTKbBluezProfile(bus, BTKbDevice.PROFILE_DBUS_PATH)



        manager.RegisterProfile(BTKbDevice.PROFILE_DBUS_PATH, BTKbDevice.UUID,opts)



        print("Profile registered ")





    #read and return an sdp record from a file

    def read_sdp_service_record(self):



        print("Reading service record")



        try:

            fh = open(BTKbDevice.SDP_RECORD_PATH, "r")

        except:

            sys.exit("Could not open the sdp record. Exiting...")



        return fh.read()   







    #listen for incoming client connections

    #ideally this would be handled by the Bluez 5 profile 

    #but that didn't seem to work

    def listen(self):



        print("Waiting for connections")

        self.scontrol=BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.L2CAP)

        self.sinterrupt=BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.L2CAP)



        #bind these sockets to a port - port zero to select next available      

        self.scontrol.bind((self.MY_ADDRESS,self.P_CTRL))

        self.sinterrupt.bind((self.MY_ADDRESS,self.P_INTR ))



        #Start listening on the server sockets 

        self.scontrol.listen(1) # Limit of 1 connection

        self.sinterrupt.listen(1)



        self.ccontrol,cinfo = self.scontrol.accept()

        print ("Got a connection on the control channel from " + cinfo[0])



        self.cinterrupt, cinfo = self.sinterrupt.accept()

        print ("Got a connection on the interrupt channel from " + cinfo[0])





    #send a string to the bluetooth host machine

    def send_string(self,message):



     #    print("Sending "+message)

         self.cinterrupt.send(message)







#define a dbus service that emulates a bluetooth keyboard

#this will enable different clients to connect to and use 

#the service

class  BTKbService(dbus.service.Object):



    def __init__(self):



        print("Setting up service")



        #set up as a dbus service

        bus_name=dbus.service.BusName("org.yaptb.btkbservice",bus=dbus.SystemBus())

        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self,bus_name,"/org/yaptb/btkbservice")



        #create and setup our device

        self.device= BTKbDevice();



        #start listening for connections

        self.device.listen();





    @dbus.service.method('org.yaptb.btkbservice', in_signature='yay')

    def send_keys(self,modifier_byte,keys):



        cmd_str=""

        cmd_str+=chr(0xA1)

        cmd_str+=chr(0x01)

        cmd_str+=chr(modifier_byte)

        cmd_str+=chr(0x00)



        count=0

        for key_code in keys:

            if(count<6):

                cmd_str+=chr(key_code)

            count+=1



        self.device.send_string(cmd_str);       





#main routine

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # we an only run as root

    if not os.geteuid() == 0:

       sys.exit("Only root can run this script")



    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

    myservice = BTKbService();

    gtk.main()
```

Following error is this

```
pi@jeanberry:~/BlogCode/btkeyboard/server $ sudo python btk_server.py

Setting up service

Setting up BT device

Configuring for name DeskPi_BTKb

Configuring Bluez Profile

Reading service record

Profile registered 

Waiting for connections

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "btk_server.py", line 227, in <module>

    myservice = BTKbService();

  File "btk_server.py", line 199, in __init__

    self.device.listen();

  File "btk_server.py", line 160, in listen

    self.scontrol.bind((self.MY_ADDRESS,self.P_CTRL))

  File "build/bdist.linux-armv7l/egg/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 205, in bind

_bluetooth.error: (98, '\xec\xa3\xbc\xec\x86\x8c\xea\xb0\x80 \xec\x9d\xb4\xeb\xaf\xb8 \xec\x82\xac\xec\x9a\xa9 \xec\xa4\x91\xec\x9e\x85\xeb\x8b\x88\xeb\x8b\xa4')
```

I have no idea why this happens. I tried turning background bluetooth off but that doesn't seem to solve the problem.

I also found this link:
https://github.com/mlabviet/BL_keyboard_RPI

both btk_server code seems pretty much same and I also have same problem when running btk_server.py. If I put empty string or any random BD address, I don't get error message but it stays in ' Waiting for connections'.

I don't think the code has any problem because once I didn't get error message( in BL_keyboard_RPI) when I boot my raspberry pi and after running ./boot.sh and running btk_server.py with my rpi3 bd address. Instead, it stayed on waiting for connection and got connected not with my laptop but with my bluetooth keyboard I use(which wasn't my intention). After that, I closed the terminal and tried again but failed. I also rebooted raspberry pi multiple times but still failed.

Can someone tell me what is the reason behind this error?